# How to solve $4(3x^3 -2000)/x^2 = 0$?

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

The equation is $4(3x^3 -2000)/x^2 = 0$, and the function on the left side of the equation is the derivative of $f(x) = 6x^2 + 8000/x$.  I'm looking for the local minimum.  A computer gives the answer $(10/3) \sqrt[3]{18}$.  I'm not supposed to use a calculator or a CAS, so I'm puzzled as to which strategy I could find here.  I do know the shape of the graph of $f(x)$ and I can see how the computer answer makes sense.  So the question is --- is there an easy strategy anywhere that I can't seem to notice?

Comment: Are you supposed to have $12x$ or $12x^3$ on top? It’s different in the question and the title.

Comment: I fixed it.  I had written $f(x)$ just like its derivative, actually.  Now $f(x)$ is correct.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you confused as to solving your original equation symbolically, or by evaluating/estimating the solution numerically?

Comment: I wanted to solve it symbolically without the use of a computer.  (In the end I also wanted to understand why the computer solution was equal to the one I got, after I understood how to solve the equation.  I did find that too.  So I'm all good here.  Thank you for your attention.)

Comment: Alt. hint: $f$ is decreasing for $x \lt 0$, and for $x \gt 0$ by AM-GM $f(x) = 6 x^2 + \frac{4000}{x} + \frac{4000}{x} \ge 3\, \sqrt[3]{96 \cdot 10^6}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so we take the function $f(x)=6x^2+\frac{8000}{x}$. Differentiating this yields:

$$f’(x)=12x-\frac{8000}{x^2}$$

Setting this to $0$ and multiplying by $x^2$, this becomes:

$$0=12x^3-8000,\text{  }x\neq 0$$

Which is a relatively simple algebra problem. Then use the second derivative test to determine what kind of extremum that point is.

You took your derivative wrong, hence why you got a different function for $f’(x)$. The power rule states that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^a)=ax^{a-1}$$

For all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you.  Following your directions, I took the second derivative, which is $f''(x) = 12 + 16000/x^3$, which is positive for all $x > 0$, therefore the curve is concave up and the solution $x = \sqrt[3]{2000/3}$ is a local minimum.  As a plus, I'm trying to see how the computer answer is the same as ours.  I know $2000 = 2^4 \cdot 5^3$, therefore $\sqrt[3]{2000/3} = 10 \sqrt[3]{2/3}$.  Now, it seems that putting $3^2/3^2$ inside the radical allows us to have $18$ inside and pulling $1/3$ out.  I see.  Thank you.

Comment: I had still a typo in $f(x)$ (a negative sign that was supposed to be a plus), which made you think I took the derivative wrong.  I fixed it again.  Sorry about that.  Thank you so much for your attention.